# How do I test generators for delegated properties?

Tags: testing, kotlin, delegated-properties

In my current project there is a class that will later on be implemented by many others. This class provides some generators for delegated properties.

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected val delegated1 get() = new Delegated1Impl()
    protected val delegated2 get() = new Delegated2Impl()
    ...
}
```

This base class can be used this way:

```
class Example : BaseClass() {
    var field1 by delegated1
    var field2 by delegated2
}
```

Now I want to test these delegated generators. Some of them contain logic which  I want to test, but for now I only want to know that everytime they are called they return a new instance.

Now my question is: how can I test these generators? 
The generators are not visible outside of extending classes so I cannot simply create an instance of it and call these methods.

```
@Test
fun `delegated1 should always return a new instance`() {
    val target = object: BaseClass()

    val first = target.delegated1    // This does not work since it is protected
    val second = target.delegated1

    assertTrue(first !== second)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new object created whenever you "call" the `get` method. So how to test it? With a **provider**

A `Provider<T>` is just an object that provides you new instances of a concrete class. Its signature is something like this:

```
interface Provider<T> {
    fun get() : T
}
```

So you need to inject a new `Provider<T>` into your `BaseClass`:

```
abstract class BaseClass(
        private val implementation1Provider : Provider<YourInterface>,
        private val implementation2Provider : Provider<YourInterface>) {
    protected val delegated1 get() = implementation1Provider.get()
    protected val delegated2 get() = implementation2Provider.get()
    ...
}
```

Now you can inject your custom providers in the test and assert that they have been called:

```
@Test
fun `delegated1 should always return a new instance`() {
    val implementation1Provider = ...
    val target = Example(implementation1Provider, ...)

    val first = target.field1

    // assert that implementation1Provider.get() has been called
}
```

Comment: There are actual delegate providers but I hoped not to have to use them since it just adds "unnecessary" complexity.